# Getting solution from exe file

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have lost a vary important .NET 4.0 C# project and all I got left is the exe file.

To get the project back I have tried this : http://mrdublin.net/2008/07/31/retrieve-c-code-out-of-exe-assembly/

The current .NET Reflector do not look the same but I have followed the guide as far as I can and I do get a project. When opening it in Visual Studio 2010 I will first have to convert the project to current version and the build.

The questions is :

1. I had to change the .NET from 2.0 to 4.0 (as it was from the beginning), why did the reflector set it to 2.0?
2. Will this code be exactly as the original, no alternative solutions or anything likes that?

Comment: Perhaps think about preventing it from happening next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the regular reflector.net and even if it did not regenerated the exect code it was better then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Reflector anymore, but I imagine it just defaults to .net 2.0, there's probably an option to change that somewhere.  As an alternative, you can check out [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Regarding question 2:  No, the code will likely look nothing at all like the original source (unless you have the PDB file).  You will lose all your comments, variable names, etc.  All the decompiled source will be very generic as the compiled code does not include details like that.

Comment: It will also include optimizations and changes to control structure.  The *behavior* should be the same, since it's working from the IL that was compiled from the original code, but it will probably do things in a slightly different manner.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried JetBrains dotPeek but I dont see how to generate the VS project from the loaded exe?

Comment: @SnowJim You can't, it's just a different decompiler that you can try, this was aimed at your first question.  As I said, there is nothing you can do to regenerate your project.

Comment: Okay? But the link I have in my first post will generate a Visual Studio project that do work? So JetBrains DotPeek do not got the feture? Instead I have to manually create the project and copy paste code from DotPeek?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to recover code from an assembly. I used [dotPeek from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It did the job. You might try that rather than Reflector.

As for your questions: The instructions you followed were from 2008 (!). The versions current for the time were 3.0/3.5, which were compatible with 2.0. .NET 4.0 was released in 2010. Maybe Reflector wouldn't set the version to something it couldn't validate.

The second one is more straightforward: I'm not sure what you mean by "alternative solutions", but you'll get a translation of the exe's IL back into c#. This means that the recovered code will be different than the original. On the other hand, you don't have the original, so how would you validate that?Y our variable names will be different and you'll lose comments, tests and everything else that would be external to the exe. Look to see if you still have your executable's [PDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) file, which will help with the variable names and actual, as-written C# code.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried JetBrains dotPeek but I dont see how to generate the VS project from the loaded exe?

Comment: That's understandable. The solution and project files contain data that aren't compiled into the executable. No decompiler, no matter how advanced, can recover data that isn't available to it. You'll have to create a new solution for your project.

Comment: And honestly, being able to recover any version of your code should be a big enough "win" that recreating the solution and project(s) ought to be a tiny task. Consider what starting from scratch would look like!

Comment: Yes of course but With my link the project will be generated and it builds without problems so I thought that dotPeek would do the same. The question is if the code could look diffrent with doPeek compare to Reflector?